# How to include a variable file in Ansible?

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-template

I have the following playbook:

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - set_fact: main_body="test_main"
    - template:
        src: test_src.j2
        dest: /tmp/test_dest.j2
```

And the following Jinja template:

```
main ()
{
  {{ include main_body }}
}
```

When I run the playbook I get the error:

> AnsibleError: template error while templating string: expected token 'end of print statement', got 'main_body'.

How to tell Jinja to include a file, its name is stored in a previously defined fact?

Comment: include {{main_body}}  try this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for [include](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#include) in Jinja2 is the following:

```
main ()
{
  {% include main_body %}
}
```

Comment: This is what works. And the error you included in the question is generated when you use `{{ include main_body }}` (as the original question stated) instead of `{% include main_body %}`.

Comment: Yes you are right. I thought I did that, but it seems that I mixed up the two notations.